# scrape data from website that turned next page when scrolled to bottom using Python and BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

If I need to scrape data from website that load next page automatically when one scrolled to be bottom of the page (i.e. endless extending the page) using Python and Beautiful, how can I do that? Is there a general approach or it needs to be tailored for each website?

Example of website: http://statigr.am/tag/cat/#/list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is a dynamic behavior like loading additional content via ajax call (as it is here on `statigr.am`) - you should either use a real browser with the help of [selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) or you should tailor your web scraper script for a specific web-site and simulate ajax calls by yourself.

For tailoring your staticgr.am web-scraper you need to use browser development tools to see what requests are made after the page load. You may notice this XHR request was made first:

```
http://statigr.am/controller_nl.php?action=nlGetMethod&method=mediasTag&value=cat&max_id=1371516699343
```

It returns json with all the data you need. There is also `next_max_tag_id` key in `pagination` dictionary - it's used for the next ajax request to `controller_nl.php`. 
So, I'd simulate them via `urllib2` or `requests` and parse the json via `json` module. Looks like no need for parsing html with `beautifulsoup`.

Hope that helps.